# Unable to listen for an event dispatched from an embedded swf

Tags: actionscript-3, embed

I have an as3 class with an embedded swf. I need the embedded swf to dispatch an event and have the as3 class action on that event. This used to work fine when the embedded swf was embedded and had been loaded as an external swf, however now that it's embedded the listener never picks up on the dispatched event.

I've created a simplified example below, the 'onMovieComplete' function is never called.

```
/*  I have an external swf file 'movie.swf' with a simple animation in it.
 *  When the animation hits a frame (frame 70 in this case) it fires a
 *  Event.COMPLETE (using:- "this.dispatchEvent(new Event(Event.COMPLETE));" )
 */

 package {

    public class ExampleSwf extends MovieClip {

        [Embed(source="movie.swf")] private var MovieSwf:Class;

        private var movie:MovieClipAsset;

        public function ExampleSwf() {
            this.addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
        }

        private function init(e:Event):void {
            this.removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);

            this.movie = new MovieSwf();
            this.addChild(this.movie);
            this.movie.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onMovieComplete);
        }

        private function onMovieComplete(e:Event):void {
            var foo:String = "bar";
        }

    }

 }
```

Does anyone know why the event dispatched from the embedded swf is never picked up by the listener?

Thanks :)

Comment: This is not relevant to programming embedded computer systems.  Retagged

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to get this to work by using:

```
stage.dispatchEvent(new Event(Event.COMPLETE));
```

In my embedded movie.swf file, and then in my as3 class using:

```
this.movie.stage.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onMovieComplete);
```

Answer (score 0):

When you embed the movie, it will be ready by time you are creating the instance and add it to the stage. You do not need to listen for the COMPLETE event.

Comment: Thanks Jens, it's not specifically the COMPLETE event im listening to to see if its finished loading, Event.COMPLETE was just an event I chose to manually fire half-way through the animation. I've tried it using other events but none are ever picked up. In this case it really doesn't matter to me which event is fired, I just need any event to dispatch from the embedded swf and be picked up by the listener.

Comment: OK understand. I was wondering why the listener is not registered with a loaderInfo instance.